# React native expo mobile app is showing network error

Tags: react-native, expo, json-server

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { Spinner, List, ListItem, Text } from "native-base";
import axios from "axios";
const Todo = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const loadTasks = async () => {
    try {
      const tasks = await axios.get("http://localhost/tasks");
      setIsLoading(true);
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadTasks();
  }, []);
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View >
        <View>
          <ScrollView>
            <List>
              <ListItem>
                <Text>Simon Mignolet</Text>
              </ListItem>
       </List>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Button
            bordered
            primary
            title="Goto homescreen"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
          />
          <Button title="Add task" />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return <Spinner />;
  }
};
```

*In the above code, I'm using json server to fetch data using axios. But while fetching data, its showing network error. And no data has shown. I'm using axios to make api calls to the JSON Server. And testing it in EXPO Go app, which is available in playstore. But From the catch block, it is throwing exception as "Network error. Please anyone help me out."*

Comment: Instead of localhost use your local network IP.

Comment: I have used Both, even IP address and also localhost... But it is showing same error @karikey Vaish

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the `port`,

Change

```
const tasks = await axios.get("http://localhost/tasks");
```

to

```
const tasks = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/tasks"); 
// 3000 or whatever port you are using for backend
```

and to successfully run it on your mobile device you will have to replace `localhost` with `IPv4 of your local network`

Comment: I did that too brother... Still same result

Comment: Make sure your backend is running at the port on which you send this request. Also, enter the smae url on chrome and see what result do you get